# deadlock caused by a cyle of locks ? unprobable event causing it or just a false intuition

Tags: multithreading, graph, locking, deadlock, cycle

Thanks a lot for your help.

I want to understand what really causes what I suppose to be a deadlock:

I have standards objects, let's call it 'Words' that contains 3 letters and a key; (it doesn t really matter for my problem)

I have a container (list) of Couples, where a Couple simply is: 2 Words and 1 couple-Key.

I have a function that is suppose to do some calculation on the list of Couples,  it might modify the letters and the key during the calculation , but when the calculation is finish we can stock the result and reset it to the initial values.

Considering a code that uses a parallel for loop to get the results of all my couples. This uses a lock on the first word and then a lock on the second word before calling the getResult() function, why could a deadlock happen ?

My first idea was that if we have :

Couple 1 : A B

Couple 2 : B C

Couple 3 : C D

Couple 4 : D A

Couple 5 : A E.

If a thread takes the Couple 5, the thread taking the couple 4 will lock D and wait, etc... to Couple 2.

My intuition is that, someway deadlock might occur if a cycle pattern appears in my list of Couples. On the other hand, I am unable to build an example that explains a deadlock appearance without considering one of these event:

- simultaneously 2 different thread have the Couples A B and B A, and each thread lock the other word at the same moment (quite unprobable to me).
- a thread takes the priority to a former one (example:well I can't find any, finally I thinks it s equivalent to simultaneously 2 different thread have the Couples A B and B A, and each thread lock the other word at the same moment. It's just that, considering a big cycle, the probability that it happends is as high as the proportion of time required for a calculation over the number of threads.

Am i right with my analysis ?

If the cause of the eventual deadlock is not due to the "simultaneously " event, I'd be glad to know what causes it, or happy if more precision to deadlock probability appearances depending on number of threads or length of cycles etc... are discussed .

Actually, I kind of have 10^5 Couples 10^4 Words.

Thanks,

Guillaume

Comment: Wikipedia in "Deadlock" article lists cycle as a necessary condition. There are other conditions, though.

Comment: *10^4 Words* Do your words all have the same frequency of use?  If not, you're going to find out really quickly that your "quite unprobable to me" is actually quite close to 1.0.

Comment: It seems impossible to me that at the exact same moment all threads fall on the exactly special situation that blocks them all.  I mean we would need a cylce like AB BC CD DA and 4 threads that at the same moment locks A, another B another C and the last D at the exact moment just before the first one wants to lock B the second C the third D and the last A. It just can t happen like this !?

Comment: I don t know the exact repartition, but it's clearly no uniform repartition. I have about 100 times like 10 Couples with same 1st word and 2nd word(only the binding key differs). I indeed feel like it s a real deadlock that happens and as you say, unless I test it with a small fraction of my list, I am often blocked. I insist on the fact that the deadlock occuring is not at all a problem for me, what I want is more an explacation of why it happens.

Comment: *It seems impossible to me ...*  Your brain doesn't work like a computer that can literally perform billions of calculations per second, with probably at least 10-20 or even more of them actually happening simultaneously.  If you write code based on "This seems impossible" and "I don't think I need to worry about that" and "That will never happen", you'll wind up with a system that doesn't work.  *what I want is more an explacation of why it happens*  Because it **does** happen, whether it seems impossible to you or not. If you say something that happens is impossible, you assume wrong.

Comment: Andrew, _a computer that can literally perform billions of calculations per second_ => What I ment was that between the two consecutive lock, just a thin lapse of time should be spent between these two 'lock' instructions. On the other hand the calculation performed on the couple requires about 1 minute (since it's quite complex actually). What makes me think that it was unprobable is that two threads should finish a long calculation at the exact thin moment. I was not denying that no operation on same objects never occur. Thank for your precision :)

Answer (score 0):

ratchet freak answerd me that:

It's important to keep in mind that between locking one word and locking the next a process can be interrupted or another can simple be faster and lock the second word.

I wasn't sure of that and this explains why my deadlocks occurs so often.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88936/deadlock-caused-by-a-cyle-of-locks-unprobable-event-causing-it-or-just-a-false

Thanks a lot,